# Bootstrapper not loading on Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: wix, burn

Hola Stackoverflowians

Testing my bootstrapper on Windows Server 2008, it doesn't launch, it just crashes with this log:

```
[07E8:0560][2013-07-16T11:36:31]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to create the managed bootstrapper application.
[07E8:0560][2013-07-16T11:36:31]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to create UX.
[07E8:0560][2013-07-16T11:36:31]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to load UX.
[07E8:0560][2013-07-16T11:36:31]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while running 
[07E8:0560][2013-07-16T11:36:31]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to run per-user mode.
[07E8:0560][2013-07-16T11:36:31]i007: Exit code: 0x80070002, restarting: No
```

It's a completely clean installation of Windows, so it only has .NET 2.0 installed.
And my bootstrapper is built against 3.0 and I've got this in my BootstrapperCore.config

```
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v3.0" />
```

As far as my searches has gone, 0x80070002 = FILE_NOT_FOUND. "Which file is that?"
Using Process Monitor I couldn't see any File Not Found other than some .NET/System Restore components. None of which I expect to be there in this setup anyway, so ultimately this didn't help.

In this scenario (Current .net version < Required .net version) I would expect the prerequisites installer to kick in, but it doesn't.

Why doesn't the prereq installer start? And how does one go about debugging these type of errors with Burn? These messages aren't really all that helpful at all.

Thanks

EDIT: Does this mean you can not have a bootstrapper target .NET 3.0?

Comment: `supportedRuntime/@sku` looks fishy to me. It wasn't used until .NET 4.0 and the value isn't documented in the main `supportedRuntime` [docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68(v=vs.85).aspx) for any version of .NET. Does removing it help?